# $scope.array showing up in console.log but not in the view after ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Edit: it's worth noting that tasks added to the third input seem to add to all users. Haven't been able to trace why.

I made a plunkr to help explain the problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/1tB0aitXjQYS4rIHcpjM?s=HCyIxFkzuuFbAQss

I'm trying to initiate an array with data from a firebase array. It's showing up when I do a console.log but not showing up in the view when I do an ng-repeat. Any thoughts on what I can try?

```
//view
 <ul class="tasks-list" ng-init="populateTasks(newDate(), key)">
  <li  ng-repeat="day in week | reverseArray">

//controller
$scope.populateTasks = function(date, key){ 
  var uri = "https://talllly.firebaseio.com/users/"+key+"/tasks/" + getWeekStart(date);
  var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(uri);
  var res = uri_dec;
  $scope.ref = new Firebase(res);
  var sync = $firebase($scope.ref);
  var week = sync.$asArray();
  $scope.week = week;
  console.log($scope.week);
};
```

Comment: The plunkr seems to be showing data now? Were you editing the global defined method populateTasks?

Comment: The plunkr shows data in console.log and adds that data to firebase but it does not show in the view. It seems like the only task that is showing up is the "sdf" task that someone added. I'm not sure how they got that one to show up or what changed since then.

Comment: Your plunkr has `$scope.tasks = new $firebase(newRef).$asArray;` Note that it's set to the function and not the returned value of the function. It also looks like you're storing Dates in your objects. Those aren't valid JSON data and will fail when you try to save to the server. See some discussion here about [Date objects](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/381) and a solution utilizing $extendFactory and toJSON.